# Почему выводит всегда True?

Tags: javascript

Если поставить  name == okName, будет всегда False

```
function checkform(f) {
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var okName =  /[a-z]/;

  if (name = okName){
    alert ('true');
  }
  else{ 
    alert ('false'); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: @Вадим95, Поясните, в чем заключается вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

name = okName - результат операции присваивания в данном случае будет истинный, должно быть name == okName
Думаю это вам подойдет:

```
if (ok_name.test(name.property)) {
}
```

Comment: так будет всегда False

Comment: Операция присвоений всегда возвращает истину, а "всегда false" будет из за кривой регулярки ( это я типа тонко намекаю )<br>
Учите матчасть, а ответ @culebre абсолютно верный ( это тоже, типа, тонкий намек )

Comment: Вообще-то name - это объект, судя по коду. Зачем его проверять регуляркой? )

Comment: Операция присвоений всегда возвращает истину// ой, вот не надо! 
(n=false) радостно вернет false, так как она возвращает результат присвоения, делая возможным конструкции a=b=c=d=100500;

Comment: Ну да, правда=), тогда надо еще указать свойство.

Comment: И еще один косяк=), я об этом подозревал, но не знал спасибо knes

Comment: я хочу сказать, что да if(var1=var2) - совершенно нормальный код, когда мы хотим одновременно проверить var2 и присвоить ее значение var1. Соответственно, я указал на ошибку в ваших рассуждениях, когда вы утверждали, что операция присваивания всегда возвращает истину. Если var2 - ложь(или, о ужас, 0), присваивание вернет именно это значение, которое истиной не является.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что это моя ошибка?<br>
Просто очевидно что тот случай который вы сейчас описываете никакого отношения к поставленной проблеме не имел... <br>
И даже если на то пошло - мое твердое ИМХО за такую запись `if(var1=var2)` руки выкручивать надо.<br>
К чему вот этот пафос я хз и еще раз ТОНКО намекну - Я ВКУРСЕ КАГБЫ и ужаса не испытаю уведев что, грубо говоря, запись `(!!var1 = false)` логично что она вернет false...<br>
И еще - `a=b=c=d=100500` ИМХО тоже ужасная запись, невидел подобного даже в С кодах, а вы тут про JS Такое пишете ппц...

Answer (score 1):

Прочесть [Особенности регулярных выражений в Javascript](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/regexp-specials) это раз! Два name = okName никогда не будет **=** и даже **==** так как вы пытаетесь проверить данные а не сравнить их! Если **okName** будет равно **test** и при условии что **name** тоже **test**

тогда:

```
if (name == okName){
    alert ('true');
  }
  else{ 
    alert ('false'); 
}
```